# Where clause in Flutter Firestore query not working with value from variable

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to stream filtered Firestore data. The query works just fine with hardcoded values. However, when I use a dynamic value in a `.where('field', isEqualTo: ...)` clause the query yields 0 results.

This query works just fine:

```
Stream getMediaStream({
  required String albumId,
}) {
  Stream mediaStream = _mediaCollectionReference
      .where('albumId', isEqualTo: 'jhQ6nwjWcj6rnDPDYZw4') // hardcoded
      .snapshots();
  return mediaStream;
}
```

But when I replace the hardcoded value with a variable it doesn't work:

```
Stream getMediaStream({
  required String albumId,
}) {
  print(albumId) // jhQ6nwjWcj6rnDPDYZw4
  Stream mediaStream = _mediaCollectionReference
      .where('albumId', isEqualTo: albumId) // dynamic
      .snapshots();
  return mediaStream;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
albumId.toString()
'$albumId'
'${albumId.toString()}'
'"$albumId"'
'\'$albumId\''
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the problem was somewhere else. The function `getMediaStream` was called **before** `albumId` was set. Sorry for wasting your time.